# What would be Promise.race equivalent in Python asynchronous code?

Tags: javascript, python, asynchronous, promise, python-asyncio

I'd like to reproduce javascript's Promise.race behavior in Python code. I want to run group of coroutines simultaneously and return when first one is done, get its result and cancel/discard results of the ones that are still running.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [asyncio.wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) with the argument `return_when` set to `FIRST_COMPLETED`. The example code below will print `1` and the exception will never be raised. The second for loop makes sure all of our pending coroutines are properly finished. If `raising_wait` coroutine finishes first, after calling the `result` method of the created Task object, the exception will be raised as specified in documentation. Last thing to mention is that, that using `asyncio.wait` with `FIRST_COMPLETED` doesn't guarantee that we will have exactly one Task in done set if the couroutines finish in almost same time.

```py
from contextlib import suppress
import asyncio


async def wait(t):
    await asyncio.sleep(t)
    return t


async def raising_wait(t):
    await asyncio.sleep(t)
    raise TimeoutError("You waited for too long, pal")


loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
task_set = set()

task_set.add(loop.create_task(wait(1)))
task_set.add(loop.create_task(raising_wait(2)))
task_set.add(loop.create_task(wait(3)))

done_first, pending = loop.run_until_complete(
    asyncio.wait(task_set, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
)
for coro in done_first:
    try:
        print(coro.result())
    except TimeoutError:
        print("cleanup after error before exit")

for p in pending:
    p.cancel()
    with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
        loop.run_until_complete(p)

loop.close()
```